# Setting mandatory permission for a facebook website app

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions, web, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello Facebook developpers community,

I'm currently working on a multiplayer online game with HTML/JS. 
I just want to allow user to register with the game and I decided to allow them to login with their facebook account. I created a Facebook website application for that.

But when I set a `fb:login` button on my page, the dialog don't ask me for the permissions I set (FYI : i just configure them in the Authenticated Referrals section).

Maybe I need to configure the permissions in an other place but with the new Auth Dialog, I'm not sure where I need to go..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Authenticated referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) have no effect on usage of `fb:login-button`, they intended for links to your application on Facebook itself.

To request permissions from user you should use `scope` parameter of [Login Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/), here is simple example of requesting `email` and `user_location` permissions (both HTML5 and XFBML):

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email,user_location"></div>

<fb:login-button scope="email,user_location"></fb:login-button>
```

**Update:**
As stated in comments those attributes may be easily manipulated by "advanced" users to avoid granting permissions. There is no way to specify which permissions will be user will be asked to grant from Application Settings. This isn't really a problem on it's own due to fact that Authenticated referrals suffer from very same problem, once user see authentication step he may change `scope` parameter to whatever he wants.

Actually you SHOULD NEVER trust to anything that came from user, so you'll better check the granted permissions after he logs-in by querying Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions
```

This will return list of permissions user is granted to your app, if something missing react on that.

Comment: The problem with scope parameters is : if someone change the DOM document with a tool like Firebug or something else, he can request less permission than requested.

Is there a way to define these parameters in the facebook developpers dashboard ?

Comment: @Rbeuque74, no there is such possibility. I've updated my answer to provide more details on subject

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm gonna use /me/permissions to check if user is cheating on me or not :D

Thank you very much ;) [SOLVED]